# Camel aggregator complete aggregation on new correlation key

Tags: java, apache-camel

Basically I have a group of large strings that are sent to the aggregator in smaller chunks. I would like to aggregate them back into the full strings.

the header has an strId, I would like to use it as a correlation key. The aggregation for previous string should be complete when we receive a header with new strId.

I would like to know if this is possible with camel aggregator

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with a bean to hold a simple state, and an aggregator with `completionPredicate`.

```
from("direct:aggregator")
        .aggregate(constant(true), myAggregationStrategy)
        .completionPredicate(method(new MyBean(), "changed(${header.strId})"))
        .eagerCheckCompletion()
        .log("COMPLETE: ${body}")
;
```

and a simple bean:

```
public static class MyBean {
    public String oldval;
    public boolean changed(String newval) {
        boolean changed = oldval!=null && !newval.equals(oldval);
        oldval = newval;
        return changed;
    }
}
```

Note that you won't receive the queued messages that are being aggregated until the `strId` changes.

Comment: I cannot use the batch size or completion time out, because the strings can be arbitrarily long. We will have one aggregated exchange until a new exchange with different strId will arrive. At this point the aggregation is complete for previous batch and a new batch wiil be start with correlation key of strId

Comment: Ah, ok, that makes it easier then. You don't need an aggregator, you can use a bean. I'll change the answer